What program/website shows the last captured piece in displaying the last move played in a position?
The following image appeared in the question Can anyone explain this sacrifice?

You can see a pawn is captured. Sometimes a position will show the last move played or whose move it is but doesn't show what was just captured or if anything even was captured. What program or website has this feature?

found position on a puzzle forum. lichess has this piece set called cardinal. maybe the pawn is kept there just for the image

@cmgchess so just manually?

yeah probably thats what i was guessing

@cmgchess ok i'll just message them. thanks for digging it up. you can post an answer if you want.
